# Multiple Image upload functionality in system configuration Magento

Tags: magento

How can we get Magento default Multiple mage upload functionality in system configuration section ?

Currently I am using  `adminhtml/system_config_backend_image` backend model for single image upload. But I need multiple image functionality same as available in edit product section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create new product attribute with type `Media Image` and scope `Global`.

It will appear within `Images` tab when you edit product.

Comment: I want multiple image upload fucntionlity in System configuration section not in product edit form.

Comment: May be this can help you. https://github.com/antoinekociuba/AntoineK_MediaChooserField